# Is there a way to package npm dependencies into a .deb package for offline deployment?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb, npm

I've created a very simple debian .deb package that deploys my node-red project to the correct directory structure on a target machine.  I also have a number of python/debian dependencies, which I've added to my debian/control file.  Everything up to this point works great.

Unfortunately I have 3 node.js npm dependencies as well, and I can't figure out how to get these packages into my .deb file.

The target machines I'm deploying to do not have an internet connection, so I cannot simply run the npm install commands in the .postinst script.  I have also tried adding the entire populated node_modules folder to the .deb deployment, but it doesn't work, it seems like there are some relative links that get broken during the deployment?

npm2deb doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for, as it seems to deploy existing npm modules into their own individual .deb files.  I simply want to include all my npm dependencies (as well as their own dependencies) to my .deb deployment in the easiest way possible.

Does anyone know of a way I can do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-deb looks like what you're after

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle the dependencies using add-node-component
Take a look at the guide here: https://wiki.debian.org/Javascript/GroupSourcesTutorial